# Using JSON file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code in my javascript:

```
var item = [{
         name: "audi",
         body: "s1",
         type: "cedan",
         price: 10,
         color: "red",
         size: "large",
         shape: "circle"
     }, {
         name: "bmw",
         body: "x1",
         type: "suv",
         price: 20,
         color: "blue",
         size: "medium",
         shape: "square"
     }];
```

i want to move it to external json file then i use this data in my js again 
why i want that , because , if i want to add new item , i want to be done form seperate file.

Comment: so what is your problem here.. you can use the json.js in your application and you can use the data.

Comment: But how to write this data in JSON file ? can i just copy paste? and how to import it from the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reading json file, First load you json file using script tag,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ExternalJson.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script.js"></script>
```

the **ExternalJson.json** wil have the following data

```
item = [{
         "name": "audi",
         "body": "s1",
         "type": "cedan",
         "price": 10,
         "color": "red",
         "size": "large",
         "shape": "circle"
     }, {
         "name": "bmw",
         "body": "x1",
         "type": "suv",
         "price": 20,
         "color": "blue",
         "size": "medium",
         "shape": "square"
     }];
```

then in your Script.js, simply parse the Json data.

```
var ItemParsed = JSON.parse(item);
console.log(ItemParsed[0].name) 
console.log(ItemParsed[1].name)
```

ref:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

You can load the JSON file by using `requirejs` or by adding it via `script` tag in your HTML code.